# how can i use jinja template and pillar in saltstack states

Tags: jinja2, salt-stack

there is my sls file:

```
  {% set java_script_path = salt['pillar.get']('script_path', default='/opt/java-app') %}

  {% if salt['pillar.get']('script_path') %}
  {% set file = {{ java_script_path }}/startup.sh %} ## seem this line have Jinja syntax error
  
  {% if salt['file.file_exists']('{{ file }}') %}
  cmd.run:
    - name: mv {{ java_script_path }}/startup.sh {{ java_script_path }}/startup.sh.backup-$(date +"%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S")
  {% endif %}
  {% endif %}
```

is using `salt['pillar.get']('script_path')` can not split other string?

example: `name: {{ salt['pillar.get']('script_path') }}/startup.sh` will raise error like: `failed: Jinja syntax error: expected token ':', got '}'` how can i fix ?

can you help me to fix my sls file to work?

Comment: You should also use a [`file.rename`](https://docs.saltproject.io/en/latest/ref/states/all/salt.states.file.html#salt.states.file.rename) state instead of what you've written there. Or possibly just the [regular file backups](https://docs.saltproject.io/en/latest/ref/states/backup_mode.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`{%` already starts a Jinja context. You do not need to try to start another one with `{{`.

```
{% set file = java_script_path ~ "/startup.sh" %}
```

It was expecting a `:` because `{` starts a dict literal.

Answer (score -1):

In simple use case such as shown in your question, you might not even need to set another variable at all. We could directly use `{{ java_script_path }}/startup.sh` in the `if` condition. Like below:

```
{% if salt['file.file_exists']("{{ java_script_path }}/startup.sh") %}
  cmd.run:
    - name: mv {{ java_script_path }}/startup.sh {{ java_script_path }}/startup.sh.backup-$(date +"%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S")
{% endif %}
```

You could also reconsider using command to backup the file, and use an appropriate Saltstack module instead.

Comment: This is completely wrong